# findOne not hitting value I know is there

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I know my current ID is in my DB but `findOne` isn't hitting it. When I console log `req.params.video_id` it shows the correct ID. How can I start to debug this? I verified that the video is in my DB via MLAB UI.

**VideoSchema Snippet**

```
video: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  }
```

**API Route**

```
Video.findOne({ video: req.params.video_id })
      .then(video => {
        res.json(video);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(404).json({ video: "Video doesn't exist" });
      });
```

Comment: First thing I would do is ensure I was connected to the correct database. Can you run ANY query correctly and get anything back from the database? Can you run a .find() and return what you're looking for?

Comment: So, if I do `Video.find({ video: req.params.video_id })
      .then(video => {
        console.log({ video });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));` . It returns an empty array

Comment: What if you do a .find without the query? I.e. .find({}). Do you still get an empty array? If so you're not connected to your database correctly. If you do get the record that you're expecting, can you post the object in question?

Comment: Try this: 
mongoose.set('debug', true);
It will log a query on the console
and you will find what the actual issue is

Answer (score 0):

Since **type** in your video schema is defined as ObjectId, try searching using the ObjectId type and if you get any results.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 
Video.findOne({ video: new ObjectId(req.params.video_id) })
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I know my current ID is in my DB but findOne isn't hitting it.

This is because `video` is of type `Schema.Types.ObjectId`. But you're querying without casting it to `ObjectId`.

Casting that would result in,

```
'use strict';

let mongoose = require('mongoose');

Video.findOne({
  video: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.video_id)
}).then(video => {
  res.json(video);
}).catch(err => {
  res.status(404).json({
    video: "Video doesn't exist"
  });
});
```